# How to avoid injuries playing badminton on concrete floor

Tags: badminton, injuries

For the past few weeks i have been playing badminton on concrete (cement) floor.
Recently I have been hearing from my friends that playing on concrete floor will 
cause knee/joint pains in the long run.

Is this true, I don't have another option to play on wooden floor.

Will wearing some good shoes help.

Suggest some good tips for playing on concrete floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say with any authority how much difference the surface you play on would make, but I think you can build up injuries on any surface.

Badminton is a high-impact sport and, anecdotally, I've seen that playing for years can lead to joint (especially knee) problems, such as: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patellar_tendinitis

Good shoes may help, as long as they fit well (so your foot doesn't slide around inside).

Getting some help on proper footwork may also be worthwhile. For example, you should put your heel down first when lunging to encourage your foot to point in the direction you are lunging.

Comment: I've developed "jumper's knee" (patellar tendonitis) despite playing on sprung wooden floors most of the time. But that's probably because I am getting older (and heavier)

Answer (score 1):

It’s really bad for knees to play on hard court. My entire life as a player has been ruined. Nothing can save the knee, one must not play on hard court regularly

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, playing on direct concrete is quite severe on your knees, and lesser known but actually worse, is the impact it has on your lower back. In your case it sounds like a good pair of shoes is the best solution. It also depends how often you train/play, but if you p[lay regularly, to avoid heel pain, invest in a pair of gel heels. As I train most days, I have these and have found it extremely beneficial in reducing heel and back pain.

The other most key thing, is lunging in a straight line as mentioned by @james. It is important to have an upright back and what on your quadriceps, rather than your back - should avoid falling forward when lunging to the net. This also significantly speeds up your recovery. Hope this helps and keep enjoying your badminton!